# How do I remove empty space above titlebar firefox browser?

Tags: 18.04, xubuntu, xfce

I am using xubuntu 18.04 and there is an empty space above the title bar in firefox browser. Does any one know how to remove it?[image] I have attach screenshot image.

Comment: FYI:  Are you aware that *flavors* of Ubuntu only come with three years of supported life (five years applies to Ubuntu Desktop, Ubuntu Server but not flavors), so you're asking about a release that is EOL.  (https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2020/08/14/ubuntu-18-04-5-lts-released/ or a recent UWN - https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UbuntuWeeklyNewsletter/Issue681#Lubuntu_18.04_LTS_End_of_Life_and_Current_Support_Statuses highlights the EOL notices for Lubuntu/Ubuntu-MATE/Kubuntu/Ubuntu-Budgie; Xubuntu didn't announce EOL but refer https://xubuntu.org/release/18-04/ you'll see it's 29 April 2021)

Comment: https://itsfoss.com/remove-title-bar-firefox/

Comment: 18.04 Xubuntu is not EoSS on Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: FYI: @C.S.Cameron, you likely know this, but I don't close vote on EOL *flavors* where main Ubuntu is still on-topic; but still think my FYI posts are useful as so many people aren't aware of the *flavor* lives never extended past 3 years; only main Ubuntu expanded 3 years to 5 for 'main' repository packages  (ie. my *Ubuntu News* hat is on for those posts)

Comment: @guiverc: My understanding is that Thomas Ward has decreed that flavors of Ubuntu LTS versions will remain on topic on AU as long as the main version, ie five years under most circumstances. This was explained in Meta, I will try to find a link to the comment. See: https://meta.askubuntu.com/a/19617/43926

Comment: I only mention this because this question was nominated for closing as EoL in the review queue but the question also applies to the main version.

Comment: :) & Yeah... I've often wondered if my FYI *flavor* EOL notice(s) do *contribute* to EOL votes, even if I didn't vote myself that way.  Thanks @C.S.Cameron